# Grouping over multiple data dimensions (pivot)

Tags: sql-server, group-by, datetime

I am logging an Events table, and want an output (as seen at the bottom of this answer), the issue is that I am getting the data in rows, but want them to be displayed column-wise.

The two dimensions are following:

- Datetime values (per Day)
- ServerId (per Server)

I think I have to group Datetime values by a time part (e.g. by minutes, or per hour) and retrieve a list of occourences of events per server, but I dont know how to write the query? Do I need a having by clause?

I've already written the create statements, the structure is as following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[events](
    [guidEventId] [uniqueidentifier] PRIMARY KEY,
    [dtStart] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [nDirection] [int] NOT NULL,
    [nServerId] [int] NOT NULL
) 

INSERT INTO events 
    ([guidEventId],[dtStart],[nDirection],[nServerId])
VALUES
    (newId(),'2013-08-01 00:01:00','0','1'),
    (newId(),'2013-08-01 00:02:00','1','1'),
    (newId(),'2013-08-01 00:03:00','0','1'),
    (newId(),'2013-08-01 00:04:00','1','2'),
    (newId(),'2013-08-02 00:01:00','0','1'),
    (newId(),'2013-08-02 00:02:00','1','2'),
    (newId(),'2013-08-02 00:03:00','0','2'),
    (newId(),'2013-08-02 00:04:00','1','2');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25e74

The end table should look something like that (daywise):

```
DateTime     | Server1 | Server2 |     Sum |
--------------------------------------------
2013-08-01   |       3 |       1 |       4 |
2013-08-02   |       1 |       3 |       4 |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PIVOT operator may be of help. Take a look at [Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

For example:

```
SELECT 
    DtStart AS Date, 
    ISNULL([1], 0) AS [Server 1], 
    ISNULL([2], 0) AS [Server 2], 
    ISNULL([3], 0) AS [Server 3]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        DtStart, 
        nServerID, 
        NDirection 
    FROM dbo.events 
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    SUM(NDirection)
    FOR nServerID IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY 
    DtStart ASC
```

Comment: made my day ; )